# How to adjust the format of Win System Environmental variables “%date%”

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, environment-variables

I have a computer running Window Server 2008 R2 Standard. It runs several periodic tasks written by Windows `cmd`.

Recently these batch jobs work improperly and i realize that the logic of the script was broken. It is because is this server when you display `%date%` variable, what you receive in stdout is:

1. Actual value - break the logic of the script:

```
C:>echo %date%
```

> ```
> 01/09/2019
> ```

2. The output of `%date%` variable should be as below (What i expect (also default format of `%date%` variable )

```
C:>echo %date%
```

> ```
> Wed 01/09/2019
> ```

I have tried several tutorial to modify on registry but it was unsuccessful. Restarting server is restricted since other important applications are running .

Please suggest any resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `%date%` variable displays date in current *short date* format as defined in the *Region* control panel (see *short date* drop-down menu):

[image: Region..Formats]

The following script shows how the `%date%` appearance changes for `MM/dd/yyyy` and `M/d/yyyy` formats:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo(

set "regKey=HKCU\Control Panel\International"

rem retrieve current sShortDate format 
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('
  reg query "%regKey%" -v sShortDate
  ') do (
    set "sShortDateBkp=%%I"
    set "sShortDateTyp=%%H"  not used, always REG_SZ
)
echo current  sShortDate format=%sShortDateBkp%  %%date%%=%date%

rem change the sShortDate format to M/d/yyyy
set "sShortDateNew=M/d/yyyy"
>NUL REG ADD "%regKey%" /v sShortDate /t REG_SZ /d "%sShortDateNew%" /f
echo changed  sShortDate format=%sShortDateNew%    %%date%%=%date%

rem change the sShortDate format back to its original value 
>NUL REG ADD "%regKey%" /v sShortDate /t REG_SZ /d "%sShortDateBkp%" /f
echo original sShortDate format=%sShortDateBkp%  %%date%%=%date%
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SF\948175.bat

current  sShortDate format=MM/dd/yyyy  %date%=02/07/2019
changed  sShortDate format=M/d/yyyy    %date%=Thu 02/07/2019
original sShortDate format=MM/dd/yyyy  %date%=02/07/2019
```